# Custom Product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was trying to create a custom shop page for a project where users can click on a product to view the details in a modal window and select some options on price variations.

What I want to do is to send the product details to checkout page upon chosen by the user.

Is it possible to do ? If so , how ?

Your help is appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish it by myself. In my **template:**

```
<a href="http:example.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=70&&price=28.45"> Custom product name </a>
```

In my **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item' , 'set_woo_prices');
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'set_session_prices' , 20 , 3 );

function set_woo_prices( $woo_data ) {

  if ( ! isset( $_GET['price'] ) || empty ( $_GET['price'] )) { return $woo_data; }

  $woo_data['data']->set_price( $_GET['price'] );
  $woo_data['my_price'] = $_GET['price'];
  return $woo_data;
}

function  set_session_prices ( $woo_data , $values , $key ) {
    if ( ! isset( $woo_data['my_price'] ) || empty ( $woo_data['my_price'] ) ) { return $woo_data; }
    $woo_data['data']->set_price( $woo_data['my_price'] );
    return $woo_data;
}

function redirect_to_checkout() {
    return WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
  }
```

This actually does the trick. I know this is not a secured way. If someone could tell me the best approach that would be great !

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user to checkout right after he uses the add to cart.

To do so just paste this in your theme's functions.php

```
  function redirect_to_checkout() {
    return WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I wanted something else. Can you please help me by telling how to send a custom product to the cart or checkout ? 

Say I have a custom template where I have a product and it's price is $40 . Once they click on the product they will see a modal window with the product details. There they will see some options. Say they checked option "one" and the price is increased by $10 . So, the total price is $50 . I want to send these custom details to cart or checkout .

Comment: OK I see. Those customs details and options you are mentioning need to be added to the product.  You can create a variable product that has those options. Upon selecting those the price will change. If you are already using WooCommerce then use it's products instead of creating custom ones.

Comment: Ah ! You are not getting me. I know how to do it within woocommerce single product page. But I will have more products in my custom template where I have to do this. NOT in the woocommerce single product page.